# Детектор движения в видео файле

Tags: видео

Всем привет! 
Есть камера которая смотрит вход на работу.
Иногда мне нужно посмотреть кто и когда приходит на работу. Для этого я пересматриваю 4 часа видео в ускоренном темпе.
Решил что проще будет если видеоплеер сам будет находить движение и ставить видео на паузу или еще что нибудь, но не могу найти ничего подобного! 
Подскажите существует ли такой софт?

Comment: Да, такое есть, например в прошивках ип камер для наблюдения, которые ведут запись на сервер, только если камера фиксирует движение

Comment: В видеокамере мне не удобно! И занимаюсь я этим редко! Я бывает скачаю 4 часа на флешку и дома пересматриваю! Мне бы в готовом видео!

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить олдскульный вариант. Если дружите с AVISynth, то в нём есть инструменты, которые могут вам помочь. 
Например, можно проанализировать видеофайл и сохранить в JPEG те кадры, где есть серьезные изменения картинки:дом с мр4 файлом сохраняются JPEG-и.

```
global avdir="F:\VideoSoft\AVS_Plugins\"
#у вас папка может быть другой

LoadPlugin(avdir + "ffms-2.17\ffms2.dll")

Import(avdir + "ffms-2.17\FFMS2.avsi")

filename="camera.mp4" # Имя вашего MP4 файла

path="полный путь к файлу, заканчивающийся \" # задать путь к MP4 файлу

imageprefix="prefix_" # префикс в имени файла JPG Картинок


Global Luma_Tolerance=15 # Допуск отличия яркости кадра от опорного
#Использовать для регистрации медленных изменений картинки

Global YDiff_Tolerance=10 # Допуск отличия яркости кадра от предыдущего
#Использовать для регистрации быстрых и средних изменений картинки

FFmpegSource2(path+filename)

ConvertToYV12()

#Trim(180, 580) #Использовать для настройки допусков, подставив диапазон кадров с нужным движением

Global AVG_Lum=0
FR=FrameRate

# Можно убрать или закомментировать, если не нужны номера кадров и время
ScriptClip("""subtitle(string(current_frame)+"f" \
+" "+string(int(current_frame/(FR*3600))) \
+"h "+string(int(current_frame/(FR*60))-60*int(current_frame/(FR*3600))) \
+"m "+string(int(current_frame/FR)-60*int(current_frame/(FR*60)))+"s") \
""")

ScriptClip("""
Global AVG_Lum=(current_frame==0) ? AverageLuma : AVG_Lum
Test=((Abs(AverageLuma-AVG_Lum))>Luma_Tolerance || YDifferenceFromPrevious>YDiff_Tolerance) ? True : False
Global AVG_Lum=(Test) ? AverageLuma : AVG_Lum
Test ? ConvertToRGB24(). \
ImageWriter(path+imageprefix,current_frame, current_frame, "jpg",false).ConvertToYV12() : last
""")
```

Ваши действия:
1. установить пути к плагинам
2. обозначить имя мр4 файла и путь к его расположения.
3. Задать допуски YDiff_Tolerance и Luma_Tolerance - тут придётся поиграться, всё зависит от камеры, которая снимала.

YDiff_Tolerance - наиболее важный, это отличия яркости текущего кадра от предыдущего.
Luma_Tolerance - вспомогательный, им задается отличия текущего кадра от прошлого сохраненного (или от первого, если ничего не было сохранено). Например, если есть медленное движение, то отличия между соседними кадрами малое, 
но через какое то количество кадров оно накопится, тогда сработает Luma_Tolerance и кадр сохранится на диск. Если поставить 255, то данный параметр будет отключен.
Открывать данный скрипт можно из любого приложения, которое работает AVISynth, например, из старого доброго VirtualDub.